# What all to download for Google Cloud Storage api java?

Tags: java, google-app-engine, maven, google-cloud-storage

I'm trying to follow the documentation on how to use Google Cloud Storage with the new clients API, so I started on the [downloads](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/java/googlecloudstorageclient/download).

Unfortunately, since I don't use Maven, i'm trying to download all of the jars. However, for several of the "other downloads", I can't find the *actual* jar. Even more so, I don't know which version of Guava, Joda, etc. I need to download. Is the latest okay, or is there a specific version that I need to download?

As for the last 4 library links, for these libraries:

- Google API Client
- Google API Client App Engine
- Google HTTP Client
- Cloud Storage API Client Library

I click on their website and I download the zip file, but there is no actual JAR file. Instead, I find a `libs` and `libs-sources` and `dependencies` folder. Am I supposed to download ALL of these jar files? (There are a ton of JAR files, i.e., in the `google-api-java-client` folder).

I don't even know if this will work, since i already use a separate version of GSON.

Is there an already packaged jar that just gives me the stuff i need to use cloud storage?

---

Alternatively, I used the deprecated Files API, and got that to work very easily. How long will that API be around?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Oh wow. apparently Eclipse plugin has a wonderful way of integrating this all with the click of a button. you just have to right click on project -> Google -> Add Google APIs. and i added the Cloud Storage API.

but for those who dont have the plugin, here's what my git diff looks like:

```
create mode 100644 .google_apis/storage-v1r7lv1.18.0-rc/storage/LICENSE.txt
 create mode 100644 .google_apis/storage-v1r7lv1.18.0-rc/storage/classpath-include
 create mode 100644 .google_apis/storage-v1r7lv1.18.0-rc/storage/dependencies/CDDL-LICENSE.txt
 create mode 100644 .google_apis/storage-v1r7lv1.18.0-rc/storage/descriptor.json
 create mode 100644 .google_apis/storage-v1r7lv1.18.0-rc/storage/google-api-services-storage-v1-rev7-1.18.0-rc-javadoc.jar
 create mode 100644 .google_apis/storage-v1r7lv1.18.0-rc/storage/google-api-services-storage-v1-rev7-1.18.0-rc-sources.jar
 create mode 100644 .google_apis/storage-v1r7lv1.18.0-rc/storage/google-api-services-storage-v1-rev7-1.18.0-rc.jar
 create mode 100644 .google_apis/storage-v1r7lv1.18.0-rc/storage/google-api-services-storage-v1-rev7-1.18.0-rc.jar.properties
 create mode 100644 .google_apis/storage-v1r7lv1.18.0-rc/storage/icons/cloud_storage-16.png
 create mode 100644 .google_apis/storage-v1r7lv1.18.0-rc/storage/icons/cloud_storage-32.png
 create mode 100644 .google_apis/storage-v1r7lv1.18.0-rc/storage/libs-sources/google-api-client-1.18.0-rc-sources.jar
 create mode 100644 .google_apis/storage-v1r7lv1.18.0-rc/storage/libs-sources/google-api-client-appengine-1.18.0-rc-sources.jar
 create mode 100644 .google_apis/storage-v1r7lv1.18.0-rc/storage/libs-sources/google-api-client-servlet-1.18.0-rc-sources.jar
 create mode 100644 .google_apis/storage-v1r7lv1.18.0-rc/storage/libs-sources/google-http-client-1.18.0-rc-sources.jar
 create mode 100644 .google_apis/storage-v1r7lv1.18.0-rc/storage/libs-sources/google-http-client-appengine-1.18.0-rc-sources.jar
 create mode 100644 .google_apis/storage-v1r7lv1.18.0-rc/storage/libs-sources/google-http-client-gson-1.18.0-rc-sources.jar
 create mode 100644 .google_apis/storage-v1r7lv1.18.0-rc/storage/libs-sources/google-http-client-jackson2-1.18.0-rc-sources.jar
 create mode 100644 .google_apis/storage-v1r7lv1.18.0-rc/storage/libs-sources/google-http-client-jdo-1.18.0-rc-sources.jar
 create mode 100644 .google_apis/storage-v1r7lv1.18.0-rc/storage/libs-sources/google-oauth-client-1.18.0-rc-sources.jar
 create mode 100644 .google_apis/storage-v1r7lv1.18.0-rc/storage/libs-sources/google-oauth-client-appengine-1.18.0-rc-sources.jar
 create mode 100644 .google_apis/storage-v1r7lv1.18.0-rc/storage/libs-sources/google-oauth-client-servlet-1.18.0-rc-sources.jar
 create mode 100644 .google_apis/storage-v1r7lv1.18.0-rc/storage/libs-sources/gson-2.1-sources.jar
 create mode 100644 .google_apis/storage-v1r7lv1.18.0-rc/storage/libs-sources/jackson-core-2.1.3-sources.jar
 create mode 100644 .google_apis/storage-v1r7lv1.18.0-rc/storage/libs-sources/jdo2-api-2.3-eb-sources.jar
 create mode 100644 .google_apis/storage-v1r7lv1.18.0-rc/storage/libs-sources/transaction-api-1.1-sources.jar
 create mode 100644 .google_apis/storage-v1r7lv1.18.0-rc/storage/libs/google-api-client-1.18.0-rc.jar
 create mode 100644 .google_apis/storage-v1r7lv1.18.0-rc/storage/libs/google-api-client-1.18.0-rc.jar.properties
 create mode 100644 .google_apis/storage-v1r7lv1.18.0-rc/storage/libs/google-api-client-appengine-1.18.0-rc.jar
 create mode 100644 .google_apis/storage-v1r7lv1.18.0-rc/storage/libs/google-api-client-servlet-1.18.0-rc.jar
 create mode 100644 .google_apis/storage-v1r7lv1.18.0-rc/storage/libs/google-http-client-1.18.0-rc.jar
 create mode 100644 .google_apis/storage-v1r7lv1.18.0-rc/storage/libs/google-http-client-1.18.0-rc.jar.properties
 create mode 100644 .google_apis/storage-v1r7lv1.18.0-rc/storage/libs/google-http-client-appengine-1.18.0-rc.jar
 create mode 100644 .google_apis/storage-v1r7lv1.18.0-rc/storage/libs/google-http-client-gson-1.18.0-rc.jar
 create mode 100644 .google_apis/storage-v1r7lv1.18.0-rc/storage/libs/google-http-client-gson-1.18.0-rc.jar.properties
 create mode 100644 .google_apis/storage-v1r7lv1.18.0-rc/storage/libs/google-http-client-jackson2-1.18.0-rc.jar
 create mode 100644 .google_apis/storage-v1r7lv1.18.0-rc/storage/libs/google-http-client-jackson2-1.18.0-rc.jar.properties
 create mode 100644 .google_apis/storage-v1r7lv1.18.0-rc/storage/libs/google-http-client-jdo-1.18.0-rc.jar
 create mode 100644 .google_apis/storage-v1r7lv1.18.0-rc/storage/libs/google-http-client-jdo-1.18.0-rc.jar.properties
 create mode 100644 .google_apis/storage-v1r7lv1.18.0-rc/storage/libs/google-oauth-client-1.18.0-rc.jar
 create mode 100644 .google_apis/storage-v1r7lv1.18.0-rc/storage/libs/google-oauth-client-1.18.0-rc.jar.properties
 create mode 100644 .google_apis/storage-v1r7lv1.18.0-rc/storage/libs/google-oauth-client-appengine-1.18.0-rc.jar
 create mode 100644 .google_apis/storage-v1r7lv1.18.0-rc/storage/libs/google-oauth-client-servlet-1.18.0-rc.jar
 create mode 100644 .google_apis/storage-v1r7lv1.18.0-rc/storage/libs/gson-2.1.jar
 create mode 100644 .google_apis/storage-v1r7lv1.18.0-rc/storage/libs/gson-2.1.jar.properties
 create mode 100644 .google_apis/storage-v1r7lv1.18.0-rc/storage/libs/jackson-core-2.1.3.jar
 create mode 100644 .google_apis/storage-v1r7lv1.18.0-rc/storage/libs/jackson-core-2.1.3.jar.properties
 create mode 100644 .google_apis/storage-v1r7lv1.18.0-rc/storage/libs/jdo2-api-2.3-eb.jar
 create mode 100644 .google_apis/storage-v1r7lv1.18.0-rc/storage/libs/jsr305-1.3.9.jar
 create mode 100644 .google_apis/storage-v1r7lv1.18.0-rc/storage/libs/transaction-api-1.1.jar
 create mode 100644 .google_apis/storage-v1r7lv1.18.0-rc/storage/proguard-google-api-client.txt
 create mode 100644 .google_apis/storage-v1r7lv1.18.0-rc/storage/readme.html
 create mode 100644 war/WEB-INF/appengine-generated/encoded_gs_key:asdfasdfasdf
 create mode 100644 war/WEB-INF/appengine-generated/encoded_gs_key:asdfasdfasdf
 create mode 100644 war/WEB-INF/appengine-generated/local_db.bin
 create mode 100644 war/WEB-INF/lib/appengine-gcs-client-0.4.1.jar
 create mode 100644 war/WEB-INF/lib/google-api-client-1.18.0-rc.jar
 create mode 100644 war/WEB-INF/lib/google-api-client-appengine-1.18.0-rc.jar
 create mode 100644 war/WEB-INF/lib/google-api-client-servlet-1.18.0-rc.jar
 create mode 100644 war/WEB-INF/lib/google-api-services-storage-v1-rev7-1.18.0-rc.jar
 create mode 100644 war/WEB-INF/lib/google-http-client-1.18.0-rc.jar
 create mode 100644 war/WEB-INF/lib/google-http-client-appengine-1.18.0-rc.jar
 create mode 100644 war/WEB-INF/lib/google-http-client-gson-1.18.0-rc.jar
 create mode 100644 war/WEB-INF/lib/google-http-client-jackson2-1.18.0-rc.jar
 create mode 100644 war/WEB-INF/lib/google-http-client-jdo-1.18.0-rc.jar
 create mode 100644 war/WEB-INF/lib/google-oauth-client-1.18.0-rc.jar
 create mode 100644 war/WEB-INF/lib/google-oauth-client-appengine-1.18.0-rc.jar
 create mode 100644 war/WEB-INF/lib/google-oauth-client-servlet-1.18.0-rc.jar
 create mode 100644 war/WEB-INF/lib/gson-2.1.jar
 create mode 100644 war/WEB-INF/lib/guava-17.0.jar
 create mode 100644 war/WEB-INF/lib/jackson-core-2.1.3.jar
 create mode 100644 war/WEB-INF/lib/jdo2-api-2.3-eb.jar
 create mode 100644 war/WEB-INF/lib/joda-time-2.4.jar
 create mode 100644 war/WEB-INF/lib/jsr305-1.3.9.jar
 create mode 100644 war/WEB-INF/lib/transaction-api-1.1.jar
```

apparently it's listed here:
https://code.google.com/p/google-api-java-client/wiki/Setup#Download_Library_with_Dependencies

just look for the eclipse plugin section.